Docker not mounting properly when using docker run
I am using an ubuntu 22.04 LTS server to try and run my python script. After creating the image, I use this command:
docker run -d --shm-size=5g -v /home/scripts/project:/home/scripts/project image_name
My script reads and writes to a csv file. It seems to work until I restart it, since when I do the csv file seems to get deleted. I'm trying to mount it with -v so when the script reads or writes to the csv file, I can see the changes when I read the csv file in the directory, for example if I use cat. However, the csv file always seems to be empty, even with my attempt at mounting the container and after I know my program has made changes to the csv file. How do I change my run command so the script writes to the csv file in the directory that I specified?
Here's the dockerfile that I use to create the image:
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENV TZ="America/Los_Angeles"

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

RUN apt-get clean

CMD ["python3.11", "-u", "bot.py"]


Unrelated to your question, but note that running apt-get clean the way you're doing it here does nothing but increase the size of the image. For apt-get clean to be effective you need to run it in the same RUN statement as your other apt commands.

It would help if you provided a [mcve], I guess you'd even find the problem yourself that way.

@larsks, would I have several apt-get clean then in the dockerfile?

Possibly, or combine your apt operations into a single RUN command.

It's not clear what your bot.py script is doing, but presuming that it writes to a file in the current directory.
Here's a dummy script:
from datetime import datetime
import time

print("Running bot...")

with open("output.csv", "wt") as fid:
    for i in range(10):
        output = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        # Write to file.
        print(f"- Writing '{output}'.")
        fid.write(output+"\n")
        # Flush buffer so that write happens immediately.
        fid.flush()
        time.sleep(5)

print("Done!")

It writes content to the file output.csv in the current directory.
FROM python:3.11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR /app

ENV TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "bot.py"]

The current (working) directory on the container is /app, so when you volume mount you need to use this as the target.
docker build -t 78276951 . && docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app 78276951

The -v $(pwd):/app will mount the current directory on the host onto /app on the container. The output will then be written to output.csv in the current directory on the host.
Equally you could have -v /home/scripts/project:/app if you want the file to be specifically created in the /home/scripts/project directory on the host.
The screenshot below shows the container running (top panel) and the output of tail -f tracking the content of the file on the host.


Thank you! I just had to change the dockerfile a bit, in the CMD: CMD ["python3.11", "-u", "bot.py"] (from the dockerfile you provided). The csv is being changed in the specified directory now, which was my original question.

Great. I think that the original CMD that I had should suffice. I believe that python links to python3.11 and the -u option is covered by the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable. But either way I'm very pleased that you're sorted now!
